# How windows drivers talk to Hardware?

Tags: windows, driver, hardware

I am curious about the different ways windows drivers interact with the hardware. For example, some drivers might use a function, others a macro, and others might hard-code the register addresses directly into their code. There are probably other ways as well.

1. Can someone please let me know about the different ways of interaction.
2. Also, I would like to know, given a particular driver, How can we find out how is it interacting, if we have all the source files including the .vcxproj and other binaries. ?

Any help is really appreciated.

TIA. :-)

Comment: You might have better luck searching for Linux driver source code.  I suspect Microsoft is sensitive about who sees their source code.

Comment: The WDK has all the source code you'd ever want, google "windows wdk samples" to find it.

Comment: Hans, could you guide me which specific source file should I look for in order to understand how is the driver intetacting. As, each driver will have a lot of source files. Please guide me with this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of device. for example, if it is a generic PCI Device then the access to the hardware is done "directly" to the HW, meaning Windows map the PCI MMIO to some virtual address and the driver interacts with it.

Microsoft recommended using HAL Function in order to prevent issues with compiler optimization, e.g. to use [`READ_REGISTER_UCHAR()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-read_register_uchar) macro to read BYTE from a device register.

USB, for example, is a subsystem that has a big stack and there is a USB controller that manages access to the device. so, in this case, you will need to use a function to access the device register.

You can find a lot of [Microsoft driver samples](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples) in GitHub

Comment: Thanks for this info @Baget. So, in case of PCI device, drivers use virtual address to inetract with the device.? What about Audio drivers ? Which category do they fall in ?

Comment: in PCI the driver maps the physical address to a virtual address. now PCI And USB are device Hardware, Audio drivers is a Miniport driver, which means that windows manage the upper level of the audio subsystem and Miniport driver bridge between the subsystem and the HW, you can have both PCI and USB Audio devices.

Comment: Alright . So in case of audio drivers , miniport drivers are the one actualy interacting with the hardware ? And by "both PCI and USB Audio devices." " you mean audio drivers can either use virtual address method or device register ?

Comment: Please excuse me for the silly questions but where can I see the actual device interaction in the sample source files. For example : in here https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/audio/sysvad , which file demonstrates the actual communication.?

Comment: As there are a lot of source files under a driver package, If you could guide me where to exactly look for , for one of the driver, I can follow the same for finding about other drivers.